# finding the best way to design this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[image]

is it possible to make one side of container small and other big as shown in this picture, in flutter.
If yes, how?

EDIT: I have accepted the answer which helps in this case.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: how is it possible to use skew widget and circular. container together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to use Transform on the Container(); the only limitation here would be to stop Container's children from being skewed too.
You can use the Transform class as a starting point for this, like this:

```js
Transform(
  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
  transform: Matrix4.identity()
  ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.01)
  ..rotateY(-(5 / (180 / math.pi))),
  child: ItemContainerWidget(),
)
```

That would give you something like this -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)

flutter_custom_clippers: ^2.0.0

```
ClipPath(
            clipper: RoundedDiagonalPathClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 320,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text("RoundedDiagonalPathClipper()")),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: this almost helped me, but my smaller side is on the other end, also its not flexible to height

Comment: U can use Transform.rotate for rotation according to requirement

Comment: again its not completely rounded borders on all corners